# Reference to project not updating vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reference

i have searched the site for any previous issue like i am facing but can not find any , so i am posting my issue which is , i have a solution in which i have 4 projects lets say proj1,proj2,proj3,proj4 and previously proj3 was in some other folder lets say it was on desktop and now i have copied that proj3 folder to bin folder of my solution and i have updated reference to proj3 but it is still pointing to previous folder which is on desktop and i can not update any code into proj3 which is in my bin folder hope it make sense :s please help me out i have done all things like clean rebuild ,restart solution e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Point your new Project3 which is in bin folder.

> Step 1: Delete the Existing project from the Solution
>
> Step 2: Right Click the solution then -> add existing project
>
> Step 3 :Choose the .csproj file in  new project location and select
>
> Step4 : Update reference.

Comment: i have done this before ,the real thing that helped me was to edit .csproj file with notepad and pointing the reference to actual path and one more thing that is so shameful to describe that i was actually putting breakpoints on a class file which was loaded from old location :D so that is why it was not getting hit but editing .csproj file helped me alot thanks for ur valuable suggestion

Comment: Editing the .csproj is good but this is the 'quick and dirty way' of solving the task.